# Vista Remote Desktop mouse not working

Tags: windows-vista, remote-desktop

I can remote desktop from a laptop (Vista Home Premium) to a desktop PC (Vista Business) and have worked like this in the past with no problems.  I have tried to log in just now however and the remote desktop doesn't seem to receive any mouse actions.  The mouse moves however no clicks work.

I've tried all different settings within RD and have rebooted both machines, and the issue still remains.  Any ideas?

Thanks,
Macros

Comment: Does keyboard input work? Can you tab around to the various buttons and input boxes?

Comment: Can you have someone reboot the desktop? Also, does it matter whether you are using touchpad or external mouse?

Comment: @Nonapeptide - Keyboard input works fine, can tab around and use everything

@flashkube - rebooted the desktop, no change.  Have only tried using touchpad, will grab an external mouse and try

Answer (score 1):

Some antivirus programs block mouse clicks.  I had this issue sometimes with kaspersky before I set logmein as a trusted app.